# Is possible to have two UICollectionViewLayout for a single UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Is is possible to use two `UICollectionViewLayout` in a `UICollectionView` and use the desired `UICollectionViewLayout` and load them based on the `indexpath.item`?

Answer (score 0):

No. You can't. Till iOS 7 you either use the flow layout they provide by default or subclass UICollectionViewLayout and create your own custom layout.

Actually the beauty of `UICollectionViewLayout` lies in `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` that contains all info like frame, size etc. in order to make your `UICollectionViewCell` look fancy.

During subclassing of UICollectionLayout you'll be overriding the below mentioned method in order to return UICollectionViewLayoutAttribute on basis of your cell's index path.

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return [self.layoutInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
}
```

Here are two great tutorials on creating your custom UICollectionViewLayout : [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html) and [Skeuo](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial).

Hope this helps.